# How to set a never expired refresh token for uaa (or gateway?)

Tags: jhipster

Created a gateway to serve restful api, it does not depend on cookie, now want to configure a never expired refresh token so that mobile app users do not need to input username/password repeat.

Found the refresh-token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me parameter in application-xxx.yml which is set to 7 days for dev profile, how to set a never expired refresh token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it's an int, you could use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is 2147483647 seconds so roughly 68 years.

I'm not sure the proprerty to configure is related to the "remember me" feature.

Look at `UaaConfiguration` and and `UaaProperties` classes, it seems to me that the property name should be `uaa.webClientConfiguration.accessTokenValidityInSeconds` or `uaa.web-client-configuration.access-token-validity-in-seconds` if you prefer dash notation.

I haven't tested it.